# No time reported

Tags: c++, time, clock

I've got a C++ program that implements a gaussian elimination.
It compiles and runs OK in the calculation part, but before it's supposed to tell the time spent on the calculation it crashes with a segfault.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    // initialize random seed:
    srand (time(NULL));

    vector<vector <double> > a(N, vector<double>(N+1)) ;
    double buf;
    vector<double> x(N);    

    unsigned int i,j,k;

    clock_t t;
    t = clock();

    double prectime=omp_get_wtime();


    //#pragma omp parallel for shared() private() num_threads()

    //matrix and right-side vector initialisation
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N+1; j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=(1+rand() % 100)/25.0;
            //cout << "a[" << i << "][" << j <<"] = " << a[i][j] << endl;
        }   
    }

    //there
    for(i = 0; i < N -1; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            buf=a[i][i]/a[j][i];
            //cout << "buf = " << buf << endl;
            for (k = 0; k <= N; k++)            
                {
                    a[j][k] = a[j][k]*buf - a[i][k];
                    //cout << "a[" << j << "][" << k <<"] = " << a[j][k] << endl;
                }
        }   
    }

    // & back again =)
    x[N-1] = a[N-1][N]/a[N-1][N-1];
    for(i = N-2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        buf = 0;
        for (j = i+1; j < N; j++)
            {
                buf += a[i][j] * x[j];
                //cout << "buf = " << buf << endl;          
            }
        x[i]=(a[i][N] - buf)/a[i][i];
        cout << "x[" << i << "] = " << x[i] << endl;    
    }

    prectime=omp_get_wtime()-prectime;  
    t=clock()-t;

    cout << "The thingy is calculated in  " << t << "clicks("<< ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<" seconds) " << endl;
    cout << "Actual time spent is probably " << prectime << "seconds "<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It's compiled with

```
g++ -Wall -fopenmp
```

,but I think the OpenMP part can be disregarded for now (it's not used at this stage).

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: if I add `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to the `g++` flags already used, it compiles and runs OK and shows the time as expected. Still doesn't help me understand why and what went wrong, though.

Comment: Start by running in a debugger to find out where the crash happens. Then examine the values of all involved variables to see if they all seem okay. And make sure that you're not indexing out of bounds anywhere.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to update your question title to actually indicate the problem (the crash).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I should, but I can't really word it right. "No time reported and it crashes before that" isn't really a helpful titile.
to WernerHenze, as I understand it all `a` elements are non-zero.

Comment: You should build in debug mode. MSVC for example adds index checks to `vector::operator[]()` in debug mode.

Comment: About your edit, did this happen with the code you already have posted or with my suggestion? I feel you just got (un)lucky and the program terminated normally.

Comment: @G.Samaras, it compiled and ran fully with the `for(int i = N-1; i -- > 0; )` version of the loop.

Comment: @Chiffa that's it! However, I suugest you utilize the third part of the for loop for decrementing `i` (that's why there is a third part in the for loop I guess). It's ok by doing it like this, but to me it seems unnecessary. I am going to update now my answer to say more precisely what went wrong. Check it in 1-2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are falling into an ***infinite loop*** here:

```
for(i = N-2; i >= 0; i--)
```

because `i` is an `unsigned int`, thus when you want it to become -1, it overflows (which means that you are indexing wrongly your array, since **you are going out of bounds**). As a result, you are not reaching the point where the timing should appear. In general, you should first be sure that your program is correct and then measure it's time.

Try setting `i` to an `int`, rather than an `unsigned` one.

---

So what went wrong?

Either your program would run infinitely, because of the infinite loop,

*or*

it would crash, which would be the most likely scenario to happen, since `i` would take a really big value (max of `unsigned int` in your system) and would access array `a` invalidly, thus causing an out of bounds access, which would probably result in a segmentation fault.

By changing `i` to `int`, we allow `i` to be negative too, thus it can get the value -1, making the loop discussed in this answer OK, since it will not enter the body of the loop when `i` becomes negative.

When dealing with unsigned integers and for loops that decrement the counter, always be aware of the danger of an overflow! It is common to change the type of your counters to `unsigned int`, rather than `int`, in order to get rid of this warning:

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

however, you should never forget that decrementing an unsigned integer should be used with caution!

Comment: Did it, didn't help. I've developed a habit of making loop variables `unsigned ints` to stop a compiler warning. I might have been wrong to do so.

Comment: Not really. I have been in this position too @Chiffa. Where did you go into an infinite loop with `int i`?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll probably consider this the right answer and proceed to the parallel part of this experiment =)
Extra thanks for mentioning the compiler warning and reminding about the loop logic.

Comment: You are welcome @Chiffa. Always be sure that your program is correct before proceeding to the time measurements. Good luck with that, I have a distributed project kicking off at the moment, so I feel you! You got my +1 for the warning case too.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int i;
for(i = N-2; i >= 0; i--)
```

`i>=0` will always be true, this is an endless loop and the loop body will access `a[i][j]` with an invalid index I.

Better change your loop to

```
for(i = N-1; i-- > 0; )
```

Comment: Tried the changed loop, got the same result.

Comment: @Chiffa Changed your code and tried it here. Works.

Comment: I changed the `unsgined int` to just `int` and tried both the original version of the loop and the ones you and Samaras suggested. But neither worked.